# Minimum distance between two functions involving integration

Tags: integration, functions, indefinite-integrals, maxima-minima

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two differential functions such that $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{2} + 1 - x \int_0^x{g(t)}dt $ and  $g(x) = x - \int_0^1{f(t)}dt $. Also suppose $\alpha = min |f(x) - g(x) |$  for all values of $ x \in \mathbb R , \beta = $ minimum distance between the curves $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Two questions asked based on this given fact is:

1) Find the value of $\left( \alpha + \beta \right)$
$$(a) \frac{7\sqrt{2}}{3}
\\(b) \frac{14}{3}
\\(c) \frac{7}{3} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)
\\(d) \frac{7}{3} \left( 1 + \sqrt{2} \right)
$$

2) If $h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and $m$ = Number of points of extrema of $h(x)$
and $n$ = Number of critical points on the graph $y = h(x)$ , then $(m+n)$ is equal to
$$(a) 3
\\(b) 4
\\(c) 5
\\(d) 6
$$

I could not get any idea to start solving the problem. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: substitute the expression for $g$ in to the first equation and find $f$ and $g$ explicitly. You will get $f(x)=1+(3/2)x^{2}$ and $g(x)=x-3/2$.